# Logstash - find in array where object's field contains

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have an array which contains an object with a key and value. I'd like to check if the "key" field equals something.

This works -

```
if "MyTest" in [doc][customInput][tags][0][key]             
mutate {  add_field  => {"[doc][test]" => "5555"}}
```

But I hard coded the [0] index, the relevant entry might not be the first in the array.

How can I write it?

Comment: it's quite unclear here "the relevant entry might not be the first in the array"? Even thought it isn't the first item in an array, it'll anyways search the whole array right?

Comment: @Darth_Vader - It will search the whole array, but if the arrray contained primitive strings it would be OK, the problem is I need to access the "key" field inside the object (each element's array is an object) and that is what I don't know to do without hard coding the [0] index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a ruby filter for that purpose (couldn't find any way to do it without it):

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
                myArray = event['doc']['customInput']['tags']   
                if myArray && myArray.detect{|t| t['key'] == "MyTest"}      
                    event['doc']['test'] = tags_array.detect{|t| t['key'] == 'MyTest'}['value']
                end         
                "
         }
       }
```